# Can not run localhost in mac

Tags: php, macos

I am trying to use PHP in mac. But when I try to run php file it print the php codes. Not execute that php code. So I search some sources and try to solve. But nothing helps me. Now I am trying to execute apachectl -S from terminal. But I am getting following error. Please let me any idea to resolve my issue.

```
Prabus-MacBook-Pro:bin prabuganesan$ apachectl -S
VirtualHost configuration:
ServerRoot: "/usr"
Main DocumentRoot: "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
Main ErrorLog: "/private/var/log/apache2/error_log"
Mutex default: dir="/private/var/run/" mechanism=default 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
PidFile: "/private/var/run/httpd.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="_www" id=70 not_used
Group: name="_www" id=70 not_used
Prabus-MacBook-Pro:bin prabuganesan$
```

Please let me any idea.

Comment: That doesn't look like an error.  It looks like the config of your apache reported by `apachectl`.  Please add the error if any you're seeing and the command you're running which produces the error.

Comment: you can try wampserver for mac. for more info http://ampps.com/

Answer (score 0):

You must load php module in `/etc/apache2/http.conf` by uncommenting the line (by removing the heading `#`):

```
LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```